# How much faster are regular expressions processed in C/Java than in Python?

Tags: python, c, regex, performance, cython

I am looking for benchmarks that compare regular expression speeds between python and statically typed languages like C, Java or C++. I would also like to hear about Cython performance for regular expressions.

Comment: CPython's regular expression engine is written in C.

Comment: Also, why would you expect static typing to have anything at all to do with a regex engine? Regexes just work on a stream of bytes or characters.

Comment: And Cython performance will be roughly the same as pure-Python  code in CPython, because it will  just be calling the same C-written functions out of the `_re` module.

Comment: @abarnert thanks for informing me. I assumed incorrectly.

Comment: This is often generally comparing C to C to C and becomes more of a library question, since most fast regular expression functions in any language are implemented natively in languages like C/C++ for speed. regex is especially well-suited for native implementations, since the tight and performance-critical loopy logic is well hidden away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is likely to depend more on the individual implementation than the language.

Just for example, some patterns are O(N<sup>2</sup>) with some implementations, but ~O(N) with others. Specifically, most RE implementations are based on NFAs (Non-Deterministic Finite State Automata). To make a long story short, this means they can and will backtrack under some circumstances with some patterns. This gives roughly O(N<sup>2</sup>) complexity. A Deterministic Finite State Automata (DFA) matching the same pattern never backtracks--it always has linear complexity. At the same time, the compilation phase for a DFA is typically more complex than for an NFA (and DFAs don't have all the capabilities of NFAs).

Therefore, with many simple patterns that don't involve backtracking any way, an NFA-based RE engine may easily run faster than a DFA-based engine. But, when the NFA-based RE engine is trying to match a pattern than involves backtracking, it can (and will) slow down drastically. In the latter case, the DFA-based engine may easily be many times faster.

Most RE libraries basically start from a regular expression represented as a string. When you do an RE based search/match, most compile that into a data structure for their NFA/DFA. That compilation step takes some time (not a huge amount, but can become significant, especially if you're working with a lot of different REs). A few RE engines (e.g., Boost XPressive) can compile regular expressions statically--that is, the RE is compiled at the same time as the program's source code. This can eliminate the time to compile the RE from the program's execution time, so if your code spends a significant amount of its time on compiling REs, it could gain a substantial improvement from that (but that's independent of just static typing--at least to my knowledge, you can't get the same in Java or C, or example). A few other languages (e.g., D) provide enough capabilities that you could almost certainly do the same with them, but I'm not aware of an actual implementation for them that you can plan on using right now.

Comment: And some patterns are O(2^N) with the first kind of implementation, and fail with the second kind. :)

Comment: @abarnert: But (at least if memory serves) those patterns aren't technically regular expressions.

Comment: Sure, but I'm willing to bet that the OP (like most people who aren't in grad school at the moment…) really means "perl-style regex" when he says "regular expression". IIRC, even what Google's RE2 implements can't be defined as a regular language.

Comment: @abarnert: Okay, fair enough.

Comment: @abarnert: That is a winning bet.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Although your answer is insightful, I was looking for benchmark wall-time comparisons between Python and C for the same perl-style regex. I have a python regex and it is slow. I want to see if it is worth learning the C required to convert a subset of my program for performance gains.

Comment: @JeffM: Perhaps you could post the regexes in question, but an immediate guess is that just using regexes in C won't make much difference. If you want a noticeable difference, you'll need to do something different (e.g., using a DFA-based RE engine or doing the searching without actual regexes at all).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Thanks for letting me know where to direct the problem. I'll look into DFA-based RE engines